# What's the difference between "--color=auto" and "--color=tty"?

Tags: ls, gnu

I'm using `ls` from GNU core utilities. The [manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/General-output-formatting.html) only mentions `none`, `auto` and `always`, but I find that `tty` also works. This option doesn't seem to be used widely, but still it was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024409/what-is-the-difference-between-ls-color-and-ls-color-tty) and [there](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/ls-%3D-ls-color%3Dtty-13689/). Is it a deprecated alias of `auto`? If not, what's the difference between `tty` and `auto`? When shall I use them respectively?

Comment: Not sure whether it's on-topic; in my mind it falls into the *Using or administering a \*nix desktop or server* category.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### There is no difference.

Looking at the [sources](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?h=v8.29#n920):

- `always` can be used interchangeably with `yes` and `force`
- `never` can be used interchangeably with `no` and `none`
- `auto` can be used interchangeably with `tty` and `if-tty`.

They are all GNU-isms. :)

Comment: You may want to replace the link with [a tagged version](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/ls.c?h=v8.29#n920). Currently the anchor has deviated.